# Which sentence is used to convey this concept in AmE?

Tags: american-english, verb-usage

**Son:** Hey daddy, I need 10,000 dollar by tomorrow!
**Father:** (He begins to think about the fact that this is a big money and I don't have such amount of money 'at least for now'! He says:)

> - But from where should I **procure** all that money?
> - But from where should I **attain** all that money?
> - But from where should I **obtain** all that money?
> - But from where should I **gain** all that money?

Comment: AmE or BrE does not matter...but InE (International English) has a straight and simple way: *From where should I **get** this big amount in such a short period*. I just spoke it the way I'd do. But to answer, you missed a good verb there ***'get'***. And yes, you probably want to say 'by' tomorrow.

Comment: As usual prompt and to the point. Thank you @MaulikV. Let see if others  think like you about the verb 'get' or not. ;)

Comment: @MaulikV is right but if you give a bit more background on what you're trying to say, there may be other answers that are useful.

Comment: I agree with 'get' but the sentence still sounds awkward to me. I would say "Where am I going to get all that money?"

Comment: I think there are probably not many fathers who would actually utter @MaulikV's sentence even though it may be grammatically correct.  A father would be much more likely to say, "And where do you 'spose I might get all this money?" or even, "Yeah right, dream on buddy."  "Ya got two chances of that happening... ***fat*** and ***slim***"

Comment: @Jim did you mean: (- Where do you "suppose" I might get all this money? )? :)

Comment: Or, if they were being sassy and erudite: "And where, pray tell, do you expect me to procure that sum of currency?"

Comment: No, I meant ***s'pose*** which is an informal contraction of *suppose*.

Comment: this is heading to 'primarily opinion based' now! :(

Comment: I think @MaulikV got the verb right. In my idiolect, the competing choices would be "Where can I get that money?" "Where can I get that kind of money?" "Where can I get that much money?" -- By the way, I just saw "AmE" being mentioned in the title. Tag `american-english` added.

Answer (score 1):

Both the "should" in your examples, and the verbs **procure, obtain, gain** sound too formal—not at all colloquial (and the verb **attain** is not even apt in this context.)

In AmE it would more likely be phrased:

- Where would I get all that money?
- How would I come up with that much money?

or something like that.

Oh, and in your scenario:

- "10,000 dollar" s/b "10,000 **dollars**
- "a big money" s/b "**a lot of money**
- "I don't have such amount of money" s/b "I don't have **that much money**!"